# OfficeJS Read text from Drop-down List Content Control

Tags: listbox, office-js, word-contentcontrol, scriptlab

This is part of my Word Template automation that we use internally. I have one drop-down list content control (seen under Developer Tag) which is pre-populated with 5 items. This drop down list is placed along with other Rich Text content control in a document.

I'm able to read the values from rich text content controls without any issue, using this in Script Lab:

```
async function modifyGetAllControls() {    
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let getAllContentControls = context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("richTextBox");
    getAllContentControls.load("tag, text, length");
    await context.sync();
    for (let i = 0; i < getAllContentControls.items.length; i++) {
      console.log(getAllContentControls.items[i].text);
    }   }); }
```

I get the value printed in Console.log. Everyones happy.
Now I try the same code for my dropdown list content control with title "dropDownContent"
I get length as "0" for getAllContentControls.items.length so it never goes inside that for loop.

Is there anyway to read the text from drop down list box please(which will be selected by the end user)? I've tried loading "lists" as well along with "tag, text, length", but no success.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Currently, only rich text content controls are supported." from [Word.ContentControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview). So there is no way to read from a drop down control.

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks for letting me know Rick. I'll have to modify my drop-down list based content controls then. Regards.